# Get value from HashCode Java

Tags: java, hashcode

I am trying to create a function which makes a random asteroid with (x, y, velocity x, velocity y) values of type BasicAsteroid, this is the constructor and function which creates a random asteroid:

```
private double x, y;
private double vx, vy;

public BasicAsteroid(double x, double y, double vx, double vy) {
    this.x = x;
    this.x = y;
    this.vx = vx;
    this.vy = vy;
}

public static BasicAsteroid makeRandomAsteroid() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    BasicAsteroid x = new BasicAsteroid((rand.nextInt()%FRAME_WIDTH), (rand.nextInt()%FRAME_HEIGHT), (rand.nextInt()%MAX_SPEED), (rand.nextInt()%MAX_SPEED));
    System.out.println(x);
    return x;
}
```

However this is the output when I create the asteroid:

game1.BasicAsteroid@6773120a

game1.BasicAsteroid@4261b6b3

game1.BasicAsteroid@2673b915

game1.BasicAsteroid@113eb90b

game1.BasicAsteroid@1abcc522

How can I output the values instead of the class@hashcode?

Thanks.

Comment: overwrite the `toString()` method

Comment: How can I do that while being able to use the values of the object of type BasicAsteroid in another class?

Comment: Also, you should pass the "rand" variable: makeRandomAsteroid(Random rand).  The reason for this is that new random objects are created with the millisecond timestamp.  If these are executed sequentially, there's a good chance they will have the same random values, so you'll get a lot of overlapping asteroids.

Comment: See answers below for printing. To access them in another class use getter and setters for your fields x,y,vx,vy. eg. `public double getX(){ return this.x;}`. In your other class use `asteroid.getX()`, where asteroid is the object of class `BasicAsteroid`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overwrite the `toString()` method

```
@Override
public String toString(){
     return "Asteroid at "+x+" "+y+" velocity "+vx+" "+vy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the method toString() on your class.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "x: "+this.x+"y: "+this.y+"vx: "+this.vx+"vy: "+this.vy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, when you print an object, its toString() method is invoked to create the string that will be printed. What you're seeing here is the output of the default toString method. If you want to print the values nicely, add a function like this:

```
@Override
String toString(){
    return "Asteroid with coords: (" + x + ", " + y + "), velocity: (" + vx + ", " + vy + ")";
}
```